# Azure Devops Excel Add-In Automation

Tags: excel, vba, azure-devops, automation, excel-addins

I am currently running Azure Devops and using the excel add-in to pull information, check status of items, and push updates to multiple cards back to Azure through Excel.  Is there a way to automate the Refresh of the data and further to automate the Update of the information if something was to change.  I have tried recording a macro then selecting the Refresh button but that doesn't appear to capture the execution of Refresh.

Ultimately what I am looking to do is create a power automate workflow that can open an excel file which has a query list from Azure saved inside, update the list, and send emails to team members based on the updated list.

I have tried recording a macro within excel to capture the VBA code for selecting the Refresh button but it does not appear to refresh.  I have also tried researching online if someone else has done this previously and could not find a result.